# PHP library to generate code diff (github style)?

Tags: php, diff, git-diff

I'm looking for an free php library that can generate code diff HTML. Basically just like GitHub's code diffs pages.

I've been searching all around and can't find anything. Does anyone know of anything out there that does what I'm looking for?

Comment: Searching "PHP diff" came up with several promising entries.  https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-diff

Comment: Not free, but generates code  diffs on PHP language structures rather than lines.  See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer/PHPSmartDifferencer.html  It can produce a diff-style output, or a machine readable output that could easily be converted into HTML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like I found what I'm looking for after doing more Google searches with different wording.

[php-diff](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-diff) seems to do exactly what I want. Just a php function that accepts two strings and generates all the HTML do display the diff in a web page.

Comment: It seems to be outdated and buggy, see "Issues" there. I would try xdiff for making diffs and perhaps diff2html for viewing. (And, because xdiff is a binary extension, perhaps it works faster than function in PHP).

Answer (score 8):

To add my two cents here...

Unfortunately, there are no really good diff libraries for displaying/generating diffs in PHP.  That said, I recently did find a circuitous way to do this using PHP.  The solution involved:

- A pure JavaScript approach for rendering the Diff
- Shelling out to `git` with PHP to generate the Diff to render

First, there is an *excellent* JavaScript library for rendering GitHub-style diffs called [diff2html](https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html).  This renders diffs very cleanly and with modern styling.  However `diff2html` requires a *true* git diff to render as it is intended to literally render git diffs--just like GitHub.

If we let diff2html handle the rendering of the diff, then all we have left to do is create the git diff to have it render.

To do that in PHP, you can shell out to the local `git` binary running on the server.  You can use `git` to calculate a diff on two arbitrary files using the [`--no-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff-emgitdiffem--no-index--options--ltpathgt82308203) option.  You can also specify how many lines before/after the found diffs to return with the [`-U`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff--Ultngt) option.

On the server it would look something like this:

```
// File names to save data to diff in
$leftFile  = '/tmp/fileA.txt'; 
$rightFile = '/tmp/fileB.txt';

file_put_contents($leftFile, $leftData);
file_put_contents($rightFile, $rightData);

// Generate git diff and save shell output
$diff = shell_exec("git diff -U1000 --no-index $leftFile $rightFile");

// Strip off first line of output
$diff = substr($diff, strpos($diff, "\n"));

// Delete the files we just created
unlink($leftFile);
unlink($rightFile);
```

Then you need to get `$diff` back to the front-end.  You should review the docs for `diff2html` but the end result will look something like this in JavaScript (assuming you pass `$diff` as `diffString`):

```
function renderDiff(el, diffString) {
    var diff2htmlUi = new Diff2HtmlUI({diff: diffString});
        diff2htmlUi.draw(el);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is [`xdiff`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xdiff.php).

> xdiff extension enables you to create and apply patch files containing differences between different revisions of files.
>
> This extension supports two modes of operation - on strings and on files, as well as two different patch formats - unified and binary. Unified patches are excellent for text files as they are human-readable and easy to review. For binary files like archives or images, binary patches will be adequate choice as they are binary safe and handle non-printable characters well.

Comment: Note: I don't think this works with PHP 7, or at least I can't get it to install.

Comment: There is now version 2 worknig with PHP 7. Perhaps it's preferable for creating diff, and can be combined with diff2html for viewing. (And php-diff seems to be outdated, see "Issues" there).